# PhpStorm shortcut for changing array key to object property

Tags: phpstorm, keyboard-shortcuts

Anyone aware of a PhpStorm shortcut or a plugin that'll let you quickly flip back and forth between these?

```
$foo->bar
$foo['bar']
```

Comment: Even if there was a quick-fix/intention for this one, there is still no way to assign a specific shortcut to a specific intention, sorry.

Comment: I personally use a regex replace. Find: `\$foo->(\w+)`, replace with: `\$foo\['$1'\]`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible to make a shortcut for this. However, it is possible to use a regex replace on a captured group like in the following example:

- Find: `\['(\w*)']`
- Replace: `->$1`

Source / more information: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-finding-and-replacing-text-using-regular-expressions.html#capture_groups_and_backreference

**EDIT:**
I have added a feature request on the official platform of PHPStorm. If you would like this feature, please vote on it. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-69017/Add-toggle-to-convert-code-array-key-to-object-property